# Executing .sql through powershell on aws rds postgres instance in VSTS release

Tags: postgresql, powershell, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have a `Postgres` on `AWS RDS` which we need to update by executing a `.sql` script through PowerShell. On doing so it asks for a password prompt, which we need to avoid. For that I already tried changing the authentication to trust in `pg_hba` and also tried

`$env:PGPASSFILE= "C:\Users\nishantd\AppData\Roaming\postgresql\pgpass.conf"`.

On executing the same manually its working fine but when i do it through VSTS release the database does not get updated nor do i get an error.

Below is my whole PowerShell script that i am using .

```
 Param
(
  [string]$DBPort,
  [string]$DBUser,
  [string]$DBName,
  [string]$DBHostName,
  [string]$ScriptFilePath
)
# Are you running in 32-bit mode?
#   (\SysWOW64\ = 32-bit mode)

if ($PSHOME -like "*SysWOW64*")
{
  Write-Warning "Restarting this script under 64-bit Windows PowerShell."

  # Restart this script under 64-bit Windows PowerShell.
  #   (\SysNative\ redirects to \System32\ for 64-bit mode)

  & (Join-Path ($PSHOME -replace "SysWOW64", "SysNative") powershell.exe) -File `
    (Join-Path $PSScriptRoot $MyInvocation.MyCommand) @args

  # Exit 32-bit script.

  Exit $LastExitCode
}

# Was restart successful?
Write-Warning "Hello from $PSHOME"
Write-Warning "  (\SysWOW64\ = 32-bit mode, \System32\ = 64-bit mode)"
Write-Warning "Original arguments (if any): $args"

Write-Host "Deploy script on Postgresql database - Start"
$env:PGPASSFILE= "C:\Users\nishantd\AppData\Roaming\postgresql\pgpass.conf"

try
{
  Start-Process 'C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.5\bin\psql.exe' -ArgumentList "-h $DBHostName -p $DBPort -U $DBUser -d $DBName -f $ScriptFilePath" -RedirectStandardError c:\tracerr.txt
}
catch
{
   Write-Output "Ran into an issue: $($PSItem.ToString())"
}

Write-Host "Deploy script on Postgresql database - END"
```

VSTS task is provided in the link. Please provide your suggestions to overcome this problem.
Thanks.
[VSTS task detail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T1app.jpg)

Comment: Do you find any errors in the VSTS, Postgresql or Windows Event Viewer logs?

Comment: What's the running account of build/release agent? (Log On as account of agent Service if it running as service) Is it nishantd? If not, does that user have the permission to access that file? Try to copy to other folder (not in user folder) and try again. You also can try to change the Log On as account to nishantd, then restart the agent.

Comment: i have tried changing the user of VSTS service to a user which has full access, I tried debugging the issue and fund that if i execute the powershell in admin mode the script is executed and the DB is updated but if i launch powershell normally the DB isnt updated even if the script executes successfully. Is there any way to run the script in background as admin?

Comment: Change the vsts build agent account to admin account, call script like this: `Start-Process powershell -Verb runAs "file path" -Wait`, on the other hand, you can try it with PowerShell On Target machine and check the result.